# Latest local notification overrides the previous one

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-pendingintent, android-alarms

I create a local notification with a *Call* action. The notifications are fired with the following code and each notification has different notification id:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(mContext, NotificationService.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("phoneNumber", phone);
    myIntent.putExtra("notificationId", notificationId);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) mContext.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(mContext, notificationId, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, startTime, pendingIntent);
```

And in the `NotificationService.class` I create and display the notification
`notificationManager.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build());`

I fire two notifications with a few seconds interval and both are visible in the status bar.
Suppose the first will have to make a call action to *1111* and the second a call action to *2222*.
If I press the call action of the first it will make a call to *2222*. What could be wrong?

Comment: Post the code from the `Service` that gets the "extras" and makes the call please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess removing flag `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` will help:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
        mContext, notificationId, myIntent, 0);
```